# Trouble installing Caffe

Tags: python, macos, deep-learning, caffe

I have been having hard time installing Caffe on my Mac OS X 10.11.3.
I have managed to run "make all", "make test" successfully, but "make runtest" has been causing the following error for some reason.

```
.build_release/tools/caffe

dyld: Library not loaded: libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3

Referenced from: /Users/***/Downloads/caffe/.build_release/tools/caffe

Reason: image not found

make: *** [runtest] Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I don't know how to install that library separately, Please help...

Comment: related issue:  https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/3227

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, but unfortunately I am aiming to install Caffe without GPU so the link you have provided was not entirely useful.

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem and solved by this:

After make test in `$CAFFE_ROOT`:

```
cp -a .build_release/lib/. /usr/local/lib/
```

The answer comes from: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/3628